# RTL8188SU datasheet

Tags: ethernet, datasheet

I am trying to communicate with the realtek RTL8188SU chipset, but I can't find any reference or datasheet. Does anyone have RTL8188SU datasheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one of those devices that is normally only supplied to OEMs, with data that is available on request. You will probably have to sign an NDA to obtain it.

Comment: I don't think an NDA will do for this kind of products. An order for minimum 100k devices/year might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I did some sniffing around on some [Linux](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/firmware-for-realtek-8192-a-761714/) [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1705004&highlight=RTL8188su) and noticed that this device seems to need a firmware upload from the host in order to get things working.

You may want to try and get those firmware files and the Linux sources to get some idea where to start.

Comment: The firmware source is probably company confidential. I don't think you'll find it in the wild.